# Does use of the default fetch group for a child entity necessarily imply an illegal join on App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I tried to add a property to my User class to get it to automatically load its child records (`contacts`).

According to the error below, this doesn't seem possible, at least the way I tried to do it:

```
 @Persistent(mappedBy = "user", defaultFetchGroup="true")
    private List<Contact> contacts;


WARNING: Meta-data warning for com.contactly.User.contacts: The datastore does not support joins and therefore cannot honor requ
ests to place related objects in the default fetch group.  The field will be fetched lazily on first access.  You can modify this warn
ing by setting the datanucleus.appengine.ignorableMetaDataBehavior property in your config.  A value of NONE will silence the warning.
  A value of ERROR will turn the warning into an exception.
```

Is there any other way to do this in JDO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The App Engine datastore doesn't support loading referenced entities at the same time as the results of a query.

Comment: How do you recommend quickly loading the referenced entities then?  I've been trying to answer this question myself for 4 days without any luck.

Comment: In Python, you can accumulate the keys for the referenced entities and do a batch fetch: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/ReferenceProperty-prefetching-in-App-Engine . I'm not sure if the same is possible in JDO.

Comment: Pretty sure this answer is outdated and no longer apply. What OP is trying to do is now supported although the same warning is still presented. One should also make sure to do what 'Sean Horgan' wrote to make sure all the children of the wanted object(s) is also fetched. According to the docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships - it should work. It doesn't explicitly mention one:many relationships using defaultFetchGroup, but when I try it, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at setting the max fetch depth on the PM fetch plan: pm.getFetchPlan().setMaxFetchDepth(int)?

- This value specifies how far out from
  the root object the related objects
  will be fetched. A positive value
  means that this number of
  relationships will be traversed from
  the root object. A value of -1 means
  that no limit will be placed on the
  fetching traversal.

You can also set a recursion-depth in the meta-data but I haven't tried that.

More info here: http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/fetchgroup.html